# Marker mouseover state in JxMaps

Tags: google-maps, jxmaps

Is there a way to add mouseover state to a marker in Google Maps embedded in Java app via JxMaps? I was looking for a way to show whether the marker is clickable or not on hover. However, I didn’t find a suitable method that sets this icon the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement functionality like this, you have to attach to marker mouse events and change marker icon (using Marker.setIcon method) depending on mouse position.

```
marker.addEventListener("mouseover", new MapEvent() {
   @Override
   public void onEvent() {
      marker.setIcon(hoverIcon);
   }
}});

marker.addEventListener("mouseout", new MapEvent() {
   @Override
   public void onEvent() {
      marker.setIcon(normalIcon);
   }
}});
```